# Making pdftex default

Tags: pdftex, emacs

The default TeXing option is LaTeX and for each document I have to use the menu item

> Command|Texing options|Generte PDF

to change it to PDFLaTeX.

How can I make PDFTeX the default TeX engine? 
I tried adding this line to my `.emacs` but it didn't work:

```
(TeX-global-PDF-mode t)
```

Comment: Perhaps (setq TeX-PDF-mode t)?  I used the menu-ing system so you could also try mousing around.

Comment: The above-mentioned variable is `buffer-local`, so it would need to be set with with something like the `LaTeX-mode-hook`.  The code used by the original poster should work as advertised -- perhaps the original poster has placed the setting somewhere before AUCTeX is initialized?

Answer (score 1):

[As of March 2014](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/?id=4ad7f97587642d6bff59bbeef0a6f9ede66ae7b1), PDF mode is enabled by default.

If you must run with an older version of AUCTeX, @lawlist's suggestion is the standard approach:

```lisp
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook
          (lambda () (setq TeX-PDF-mode t)))
```

However, there is a function for this (as you said):

```lisp
(TeX-global-PDF-mode t)
```

This *does* work on `emacs -q`.  Be sure to actually evaluate the form (`M-x eval-last-sexp` will work) or restart Emacs for it to take effect, though.